# Parsing jsonstore content

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

The data loaded by jsonstore is as follows:

```
"[{"Year":"2014","Total":"5.6","Rank":"6","Share":"6"},
{"Year":"2013","Total":"5.6","Rank":"6","Share":"6"},
{"Year":"2014","Total":"5.6","Rank":"6","Share":"6"},
{"Year":"2013","Total":"5.6","Rank":"6","Share":"6"}]"
```

We needed to iterate the response:

```
FeesByProduct_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'list',
        url: '...............', 
      fields: FeeByProduct,
        listeners: {load: function(store) {
            //create a json object from the response string
            var res = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
            // if we have a valid json object, then process it
            if(res !== null &&  typeof (res) !==  'undefined'){
                // loop through the data
                Ext.each(res, function(obj){
                    //add the records to the array
                    if (obj != null) {
                    ...
                    }   

                });
             }

        }
    }
    });
```

However,on iterating - 'obj' contains the entire value of the response rather than each row at a time.
What is being done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully loaded the store, the original json is not interesting anymore. You have plenty of methods on the store you can use to examine or manipulate the store records.

Your load listener could look like this way:

```
load:function() {
    this.each(function(record) {
        // do something with record here, for example
        console.log(record.getData();
    }
}
```

Check the [`store` documentation](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) to find other methods you could use to implement what you need.